# How do I prevent NULLs from being inserted in MySql when using user variables?

Tags: mysql, variables, insert

I am struggling to find a way to get MySql to use user variables properly in an insert statement.  MySql is inserting `NULL` where I have my variable.  Here is a portion of my installation script:

```
SELECT CONCAT("env=",@env);    //this is irrelevant debugging

SET @OV_PRIMARY_PORT = CASE @env
    WHEN 'agile'      THEN '443'
    WHEN 'fit'        THEN '443'
    WHEN 'pilot'      THEN '443'
    WHEN 'production' THEN '443'
END
;

  // this is irrelevant debugging
SELECT CONCAT("OV_PRIMARY_PORT=",@OV_PRIMARY_PORT);  

INSERT INTO IsensorDefaultConfigItem
    (item_name, application_name, application_component, initialized_time, item_value)
   VALUES ('bubba', 'bubba', 'bubba-primary4', NOW(), @OV_PRIMIRY_PORT);
```

The variable `@env` was set in a previous part of the script and the `SELECT` statement is there only to display the value for me to confirm that is working.  The same is true of the `SELECT` that contains `@OV_PRIMARY_PORT`....it is just there for debugging.

`Always` - both selects show that the variables are set as I would have expected.
`Always` - I get `NULL` inserted into my table for the `item_value` column.
That column is defined as a `TEXT` column that does default to NULL.

Comment: You misspelled `PRIMARY` in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: wow.....sorry for wasting the time of anyone who read this.